# Can `greetSomeone("world")` be replaced by `greetSomeone(name)`? Is there any side effect to this change?

Tags: java, arguments, inner-classes

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of inner class. I saw the code below from Java tutorial Oracle. My question is, for

```
String name = "world";
@Override
public void greet() {
    greetSomeone("world");
}
```

Can `greetSomeone("world")` be replaced by `greetSomeone(name)`. The reason why I'm asking this question is because I have noticed if `greetSomeone("world")` is indeed replaced by `greetSomeone(name)`, inside the public void greetSomeone() method, the passed "name" argument will be set to itself. I was just wondering if there are side effect to code like this?

```
public class HelloWorldAnonymousClasses {

    interface HelloWorld {

        public void greet();

        public void greetSomeone(String someone);
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        class EnglishGreeting implements HelloWorld {

            String name = "world";

            @Override
            public void greet() {
                greetSomeone("world");
            }

            @Override
            public void greetSomeone(String someone) {
                name = someone;
                System.out.println("hello " + name);
            }
        }
        HelloWorld eg1 = new EnglishGreeting();
        eg1.greet();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorldAnonymousClasses myApp = new HelloWorldAnonymousClasses();
        myApp.sayHello();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not if the contract for `greet()` is to say "hello world". There is a side-effect. Saying `greet()` currently still outputs "hello world", if you change it to `greetSomeone(name)` then the output may change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all why is that @Override annotation there?

You will use Override when you want to change the behaviour of the parent's methods. Your parent's methods have no behaviour as it is an interface. As a further note I guess that it will teach you that the signature of an overriden method must always match the one from the parent.

Secondly the design is kind of dodgy. It can be simplified.

Thirdly yes you can refer to the String object name as it is defined in that class and you can access the object's primitive just by calling 'name'. Why will you not get the reference printed when System.out? Because the String object handles that for you ensuring the toString will show you the primitive. When you do System.out.print(myObject); The console will show you the Object default or the overriden toString method.

So if you create an object and you do System.out.print(myObject) you will see the reference. If you override toString returning "test" you will see test.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, `name` can be passed and `name = name;` is valid Java.

However, this is a horrible design and was probably used for demonstrative purposes only. Don't do this.